# Crear condicionales comparando fecha actual con fecha de registro

Tags: php, date, datetime

Necesito ayuda con condicionales utilizando fechas..

Necesito que al crear un registro la celda de la tabla sea de color **`verde`**,

al pasar `3` días de creado el registro, automáticamente la celda sea **`naranja`**

y al pasar de los `6` días sea **`roja`**...

Hice algo en que lo cambio el color de manera manual, pero me gustaría q sea automático utilizando fechas...

Esto es lo que tengo..Gracias:

```
<?php
foreach ($respuesta as $registro) {
$tr = '<tr>';
    if ($registro['idEstado'] == '1') {
        $tr = '<tr style="background-color:#F98888;color:#B72212;">';
    }else if ($registro['idEstado'] == '2') {
        $tr = '<tr style="background-color:#F9BD88;color:brown;">';
    } else {
        $tr = '<tr style="background-color:#B7D5B6;color:green;">';
    }

$cadena .= $tr."

            <td>".$registro['fecha']."</td>
            <td>".$registro['nombre']."</td>
            <td>".$registro['direccion']."</td>
            <td>".$registro['telefono']."</td>
            <td>".$registro['estados']."</td>
        </tr>";         
}
echo $cadena;

?>
```

Comment: No queda claro cuál es el problema, en tu idEstado supongo llegará 1, 2, 3 que deben generarse a partir de un código que no incluiste

Answer (score 0):

leyendo tu codigo llego a la conclusion que necesitas algo como esto:

```
<?php

    //creas la fecha actual 
    $fecha_hoy = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //traemos la fecha de la base de datos y le sumamos 3 dias...
    $fecha_registro= date($registro['fecha'], strtotime('+3 days');


    $tr = '<tr>';
    //comparamos las fechas que la fecha de registro no sea mayo a la fecha de hoy
    if ($fecha_hoy > $fecha_registro) {
        //si esto se cumple es por que ya han pasado mas de 3 dias
        $tr = '<tr style="background-color:#F98888;color:#B72212;">';
    }

?>
```

Espero te sirva, [Aqui te dejo el Link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) para que te ilustres mejos y entiendas el funcionamiento.

**ReNiceCode...**

Comment: para que sirve '3 dyas'?

Comment: ups es `days` @Alfredo maestro meti mal el dedo xD Muchas gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta